# Lim inf and lim sup of Infinite intersection of closed sets [0,1],[0,1/2],[0,1/3],..

Tags: general-topology

Lim inf and  lim sup of Infinite intersection of closed sets [0,1],[0,1/2],[0,1/3],....

I think an infinite intersection of all this set will be singleton set i.e. {0}

So this set does not have lim inf and lim sup.

But how to prove it??

If i am wrong then what will be lim inf and lim sup?

Comment: If you have a descending chain of sets $A_0 \supseteq A_1 \supseteq ...$, the liminf and limsup coincide simply with the intersection $\cap_i A_i$. Note that what you say "this set does not have lim inf and lim sup" is meaningless: ALL sequences of sets have lboth liminf and limsup: they are well-defined.

Comment: try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem

Comment: @Crostul what will be set for given intersections of all sets?

Comment: The intersection is $\{ 0 \}$, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

We have the sequence of sets $A_n = [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ that clearly are decreasing:

$$\forall n: A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$$

Now the $\liminf_n A_n$ is always defined, namely as

$$\liminf_n A_n = \bigcup_m \bigcap_{n \ge m} A_n$$

And in this case all intersections $\bigcap_{n \ge m} A_n$ are just equal to

$\bigcap_n A_n = \{0\}$ and the union of these is still $\{0\}$ so that $\liminf_n A_n = \{0\}$.

The $\limsup_n A_n$ is also always defined, i.e. as

$$\limsup_n A_n = \bigcap_m \bigcup_{n \ge m} A_n$$

And for any fixed $m$, the union of all $A_m, A_{m+1},\ldots$ is just the first one, by the decreasingness of the sets. So $\bigcup_{n \ge m} A_n = A_m$ and so

$$\limsup_n A_n = \bigcap_m A_m = \{0\}$$

and hence $\limsup_n A_n = \liminf A_n = \{0\}$ and the sequence of sets is convergent to the set $\{0\}$.